# Pulling in featured image into default recent posts widget

Tags: loop, widgets, post-thumbnails

I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer to this, I have duplicated the default recent posts widget (not customising core) - I've added styles etc to it, however, when I try to pull in the featured image for each post it just seems to pull in the same image for each post.

See below:

```
        <?php foreach ( $r->posts as $recent_post ) : ?>
            <?php
            $post_title = get_the_title( $recent_post->ID );
            $title      = ( ! empty( $post_title ) ) ? $post_title : __( '(no title)' );
            ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink( $recent_post->ID ); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><div class="related">

        <div class="related_img"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        <div class="related_title"><?php echo $title ; ?></div>
        <div class="related_date"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> <?php echo get_the_date( '', $recent_post->ID ); ?></div>

        </div><div style="clear: both;"></div></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I pull in the correct featured image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail()` will show the thumbnail of the current post in the [Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Since you are using a custom foreach() loop instead of starting your own WordPress Loop, you can use this instead to specify which post you want:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent_post->ID ); ?>
```